# Pug to html converter for Mac. Seeking command line code

Tags: html, macos

I'm following a Pug tutorial and the narrator is using Windows. This is the command he wrote that automatically translates his Pug code to Html

Question: What's the Mac equivalent of

```
pug -w ./ -o ./html -P
```

Comment: The Mac equivalent **is** `pug -w ./ -o ./html -P`. Perhaps you just need to install pug.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to do that. After installing pug i ran the code and it returned -> zsh: command not found: pug

Comment: Then you didn't install it to your $PATH. You probably want to use the `npx` utility.